# Как заполнить класс зоопарк случайными животными в количестве введенным пользователем?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Есть класс Animal, который хранит указатель на пустоту, за которым скрывается конкретное животное, а так же его тип.

```
class Animal
{
public:
    void* animal_object;
    std::string animal_type;

    Animal(void* animal_object, string animal_type) {
        this->animal_object = animal_object;
        this->animal_type = animal_type;
    }
    Animal() {
        animal_object = nullptr;
        animal_type = "";
    }
};
```

Есть класс cat и dog

```
class Cat {
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    int hungry;
    int tiredness;
};

class Dog
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    int hungry;
    int tiredness;
};
```

есть так же класс zoo, в котором есть методы для добавления нового одного животного которого введет пользователь.

Comment: Мне кажется, что лучше сделать котов и собак наследниками от `Animal`, чем возиться с полем типа животного и указателем `void*`...

Comment: Да, возможно, но так сказано в задании

Comment: А можно точный текст задания? Неужели там работать через `void*`? Это же просто прямое нарушение всех парадигм С++ :(

Comment: класс Кот, Собака, там есть свойства.
 класс Животное, который будет хранить указатель на пустоту, за которым скрывается 
 конкретное животное, а так же его тип.
класс Контактный зоопарк, который будет хранить в себе массив животных.
и нужно заполнить зоопарк случайными животными в количестве введенным пользователем, так что бы было хотя бы по одному животному одного вида.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задание, конечно, гм... ну ладно.

Как я понимаю, от вас хотят чего-то в этом духе:

```
Animal * zoo;

int n;
cin >> n;
zoo = new Animal[n] { nullptr };

// n >= 2 из условия хотя бы по одному каждого вида
Cat * c = new Cat; // Поля заполняйте сами
zoo[0] = Animal(c,"cat");
Dog * d = new Dog; // Поля заполняйте сами
zoo[1] = Animal(d,"dog");

for(int j = 2; j < n; ++j)
{
    if (rand()%2==0)
    {
        c = new Cat; // Поля заполняйте сами
        zoo[j] = Animal(c,"cat");
    }
    else
    {
        d = new Dog; // Поля заполняйте сами
        zoo[j] = Animal(d,"dog");
    }
}
```